# iOS in Swift 3 Dynamic scrolling Tab bars like Paytm offers Tabs

Tags: ios, dynamic, swift3, scroll, tabs

How to Create dynamic scrollable Tabs like shown in the image below

[image: referance]

Please respond as soon as possible Thank you so much in advance

Comment: have a look at  https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip & https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu

Answer (score 0):

These are actually TableViewCells of a TableView which offers scrollable cells

[image]

You can use images,buttons,labels inside each cell of the TableView

You can find more about the UITableView here :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview